# How to avoid saving a new document to my mongoDB database after registering a new user?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

```
router.post('/send', (req, res) =>
{
const errors = [];

 // Creating formData that will hold user information
 const userData = 
 {
     firstName: req.body.firstName,
     lastName: req.body.lastName,
     usr: req.body.usr,
     pass: req.body.pass,
     adrs: req.body.adrs,
     eml: req.body.eml,
     cpass: req.body.cpass
 }

 if(userData.cpass !== userData.pass)
 {
     errors.push('Passwords do not match');
 }

// First name
let firstNameReg = /^[A-Za-z0-9]{2,20}$/;

if(!firstNameReg.test(userData.firstName))
{
    errors.push(`First name should have minimum of 20 characters.`);
}

// Last name
let lastNameReg = /^[A-Za-z0-9]{2,20}$/;

if(!lastNameReg.test(userData.lastName))
{
    errors.push(`Last name should have minimum of 20 characters.`);
}

// Name error handling
let nameReg = /^[A-Za-z0-9]{2,25}$/;

if(!nameReg.test(userData.usr))
{
    errors.push(`Username should be between 2 and 25 letters/numbers.`);
}

// Password error handling
let passReg = /^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*<>?]).{8,16}$/;

if(!passReg.test(userData.pass))
{
    errors.push('Password must start with a capital letter, have a number and symbol, and must be between 8 and 16 characters.');
}

const adrsReg = /^([0-9]+)[ ]([A-Za-z0-9\.\# ].{4,30})$/;


if(!adrsReg.test(userData.adrs))
{
    errors.push('Please enter a valid home address.')
}

// Email error handling
const emailReg = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.]+)@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.]+)\.([a-z]{2,5})$/;

if(!emailReg.test(userData.eml))
{
    errors.push('Please enter a valid email with an @ and a valid domain!');
}


// Checking for errors
if(errors.length > 0)
{
    const title = 'Airbnb | Register';
    const style = 'register.css';

    res.render('registration/register', {
        ttl: title,
        sty: style,
        err: errors,
        fname: userData.firstName,
        lname: userData.lastName,
        name: userData.usr,
        adrs: userData.adrs,
        pNum: userData.pNum,
        eml: userData.eml
    });
}

else
{
    const title = 'Airbnb | Register';
    const style = 'register.css';

    // INSTANTIATE MODEL [THIS CREATES A DOCUMENT FOR NEW USER]
    const newUser = new model(userData);

    newUser
    .save()
    .then((newUser) =>
    {
        // console.log('Document created');
        // console.log(`terr: ${newUser.usr}`);

        model.findOne({usr: req.body.usr})
        .then((user) =>
        {
            console.log(`This is users username: ${user.usr}`);

           if(newUser.usr === user.usr) 
           {
               errors.push(`Username has been taken`);
               res.render('registration/register', 
               {
                    ttl: title,
                    sty: style,
                    err: errors,
                    fname2: userData.firstName,
                    lname2: userData.lastName,
                    adrs: userData.adrs,
                    pNum2: userData.pNum,
                    eml2: userData.eml
               });
           }
           else
           {
               console.log(yer);
               res.redirect(`/send`);
           }
        })

    })
    .catch((err) =>
    {
        console.log(`Something went wrong -> ${err}`);
    })
}
});
```

My main problem occurs in the

```
 newUser
    .save()
```

because in there im saving the users information in my database collection.

In the

```
if(newUser.usr === user.usr)
```

Im checking if the new users username matches the user whos already saved in the mongoDB database. If the username is already available, then i don't want to save the document of the user that is registering.

Although this code is working for the front-end as my code generates an error for the user, it is not working in the back-end because multiple users are being added into my collection with the same username.

How do i avoid this problem?

Comment: Obviously if you save the user then you are going to add multiple users with the same name.  You can just query your database first to see if there is a user with the same name.  If there is not then you can proceed.  If there is then you can error out and return with the error.

Comment: Why not use some unique attribute for users, not just their names. It can be email, or may be some unique string generated on front-end? You have to understand from business perspective: when two users should be considered two different ones, and in which cases they should be treat as the same exact user.